# How to apply custom function to a text column with a rolling window in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, rolling-computation

I have the following function which adds some strings to the last item of an array and returns a number:

```
def mycoolfunct(v):
    last_bin = v[-1]
    
    sval2 = last_bin[-1] + 'xx'
    sval1 = last_bin[-2] + last_bin[-1] + 'n'
    
    v += [sval1, sval2]
    
    return mycoolcalc(v) # returns a number like 0.2
```

I call it manually by this way and it works as expected:

```
print(mycoolfunct(['axx', 'are']))
0.35
```

However, if I try to execute this function using a rolling window in pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['are', 'axe', 'are', 'fer'])
print(df[0].rolling(2).apply(mycoolfunct))
```

I get the following error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

How can call a function with a rolling window passing a text column and not a numeric one?

Comment: rolling is not supported on a non-numeric columns. What is the goal here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can imitate the rolling function as follows (where n-1 is the window parameter):

```
n = 3
pd.concat( [df[['col1']].shift(x) for x in range(0,n)], axis=1 )
```

Now you have a DataFrame like this

```
        col1 col1(lag1) col1(lag2)
         'a'      NaN      NaN
         'b'      'a'      Nan
         'c'      'b'      'a'
```

In this way, you can apply the function of your choice along axis=1.

```
pd.concat( [df[['col1']].shift(x) for x in range(0,n)], axis=1 ).apply(your_function, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently pandas doesn't support strings for rolling operations.
There are some workarounds, mostly for time based rolling operations.
I'm looking for an equivalent of the following:
`df[string_col].rolling(window=win_size).apply('-'.join)`
But this raises an exception.

I tried using rolling and it failed.
I saw the github issue - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23002
I looked for equivalent groupby functions (cumsum style) but didn't find any matching ones.

The workaround I came up with is using list comprehensions inside the apply function:
`df[[string_col, grouping_col]].groupby(grouping_col).apply(lambda x:rolling_func(x.iloc[start:start+win_size][string_col]) for start in range(len(x)-win_size)])`